# iPhone Cocos2D - Starting a scene with a specific image

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I would like to start a new scene on cocos2d, but I want to pass the image to be used as the scene background itself.

If it was with UIImageViews, it would be the equivalent of

```
UIImageView *myIV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithimage: myImage];
```

that, is, myImage is the image that will fill the entire myIV.

Talking in terms of cocos2d,

I would call the scene using something like this,

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:
     [CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:[myScene scene]]];
```

but if the scene will enter the screen, how can I specify the image so it is created based on the image (using the image as bg and at the size of the image).

I thought about creating a property on myScene to pass the image, but this will be useless, as the init will run before the property can be set and as far as I realize, the init method has to run using the image as reference.

Comment: "the init method has to run using the image as reference" why is this?

Comment: because if I present the scene without creating it first, it will be presented empty.

Comment: as shown in my answer below you can store the image name somewhere and then retrieve it from within the init method.

Comment: using this method will hard wire the code to the delegate. I need it to be free, because I will have to pass the same image later to other classes and in that case I will have to hard wire every class to the same delegate, creating a confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend your "myScene" class with an initializer that takes the UIImage as an argument:

```
-(id) initWithUIImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        CCTexture2D* tex = [[[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
        CCSprite* bg = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:tex];
        [self addChild:bg];
        // ...
    }
    return self;
}

+(id) sceneWithUIImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    return [[[self alloc] initWithUIImage:image] autorelease];
}
```

Then you can create this scene (this assumes that your "myScene" class is named "MySceneClass":

```
MySceneClass* myScene = [MySceneClass sceneWithUIImage:image];
id trans = [CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:myScene];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:trans];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always put some methods in your appDelegate to set a property and then get the value from within your init?

```
-(void) setImageToUse:(NSString *)theImageString {
imageToUSe = theImageString;
}

-(int) returnImageToUse {
return imageToUSe;
}
```

or simply save the string to nsuserdefaults and again retrieve it in the init method?

Comment: This NSUserDefaults idea is good, but not for my case, because the user is selecting an image from the library and I want to pass that image. Using this method, implies writing an image to disk just to read it again seconds later, turning the app slow as hell... thanks anyway :(   using the delegate idea is not desirable in my case, because I want to turn the code less wired, and more independent... what I need is to pass the value from one scene to the other, without wiring them.